# Display value depending on selected values from 2 Dropdown menus in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, drop-down-menu

This is what I've constructed so far: https://plnkr.co/edit/fnhKUhuTYjUTQgJLnZoT?p=preview

I want to display a value in the `input` textbox that depends on the user's 2 choices from the 2 dropdown menus. I want that value to come from the `values` array here:

```
var values = [1, 2, 0.1, 1, 3, .2, 2, 3,.3];
```

If the 1st choice is `1` and the 2nd choice is `2`, then I want the `input` textbox to display `0.1`. And vice-versa, so if the 1st choice is `2` and the 2nd choice is `1` then I want `0.1` to be the output.

And I want nothing to happen if the user chooses the same value for both menus. So if the user chooses `2` for both menus, then I want there to be no output

How can I program this?

EDIT: I should probably first convert the `values` array to a hashmap like this:

```
var values = [(1, 2): 0.1, (1, 3): .2, (2, 3): .3];
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand. How are you trying to determine the output (0.1) from the array based on the inputs of 1 and 2?

Comment: I clarified this in the EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you won't mind me using jQuery in my solution since you had it included in your Plunk.

```
var $selects = $('select');
var $output = $('#pred');
```

First I will create a map of input pairs to output values.

```
var values = {
    '1,2': 0.1,
    '1,3': 0.2,
    '2,3': 0.3
};
```

Next, I will listen for a `change` event on the select menus. In my `change` handler, I will map the values of the selects into an array of numbers. Next, by sorting and joining this array, I should end up with a stringed pair of numbers in ascending order and delimited by a comma; a `key`, just like the keys in my `values` object.

Finally, I will set the value of `$output` to the value of `values` at the resultant `key`. If `values[key]` is `undefined`, I will default to an empty string.

```
$selects.on('change', function () {
    var key = $selects.map(function (index, el) {
        return Number($(el).val());
    })
        .get()
        .sort()
        .join(',');

    $output.val(values[key] || '');
});
```